# Material Table: "data.map is not a function" when I try to render my data using the remote data method

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, fetch, material-table

I'm trying to process some data into my table rows but I'm getting error : "data.map is not a function"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the remote data prop from Material Table I used a useEffect hook with the fetching inside

```
 const url = "";
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "Bearer [I added my access token in here] ",
      },
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((resp) => setData(resp));
  }, []);


  <MaterialTable
        title="All Products"
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
```

Make sure the field in your columns match your GET schema. This table is very case sensitive..
Here is the video that helped me figure this out
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShkrK7BHTM8

Comment: this approach will make the nextPage, change limit per size is broken